# Why do PageModel and ControllerBase use the ActionResult that doesn't belong to them?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

We know that instead of a `PageModel` and page handler, MVC uses a concept of controllers and action methods, but look at the source code of PageModel:

```cs
public abstract class PageModel : IAsyncPageFilter, IFilterMetadata, IPageFilter  {
   ...
   public virtual RedirectToPageResult RedirectToPage(string pageName, string pageHandler, object routeValues, string fragment);
   public virtual RedirectToActionResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string fragment) 
   ...
}
```

and if you look at the `ControllerBase` class:

```cs
public abstract class ControllerBase {
   ...
   public virtual RedirectToActionResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string fragment);
   public virtual RedirectToPageResult RedirectToPage(string pageName, string pageHandler, object routeValues, string fragment);
   ...
}
```

I'm confused, why Razor pages uses the MVC things `RedirectToActionResult`  (controllerName and actionName), and MVC uses Razor Page things "XXXToPageResult" such as `RedirectToPageResult`(pageName, pageHandler)?

Comment: Razor pages implement MVVM, which is slightly different from MVC. Using the same words for different things would be confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix MVC controllers and views together with razor Pages in the same ASP.NET Core application, so it makes sense that you should be able to redirect to Razor pages from controllers, and to controller actions from Razor pages.

Comment: hi can you have a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688785/strange-behaviour-that-filters-have-when-dealing-with-each-request